# Flex tree populating with xml over http

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tree

i have a HTTPService providing XML on request.

```
<mx:HTTPService id="selektProdukt_data" url="{l_url_selektProduktservice}" useProxy="false" resultFormat="e4x"/>
```

so invokink the service with:

```
selektProdukt_data.send();
```

delivers [resulting XML](http://pastebin.com/cA6sqxZY)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <error_text>OK</error_text>
  <node label="Alte As">
     <node label="Single Play">
        <node label="PMx">
          <node label="Variante-B"/>
        </node>
     </node>
  </node>
</result>
```

But my tree won't get populated:

```
<mx:Tree id="selectTree" dataProvider="{selektProdukt_data.lastResult.struktur}" labelField="@label" showRoot="false"/>
```

It should show:

```
Alte AS  
|_SinglePlay  
  |_PMx  
    |_Variante-B
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `struktur` in the xml you posted - change the tree code to:

```
<mx:Tree id="selectTree" 
    dataProvider="{selektProdukt_data.lastResult.node}" 
        labelField="@label" showRoot="false"/>
```

I believe this wouldn't show `Alte As`, the root tag. Set `showRoot="true"` to show that.